# How to get PNR expiry

Tags: sabre

Is there any way I can get expiry date of PNR or maximum time allowed for booking in Sabre's Bargain Finder Max Query? I need to get the expiry of PNR which is provided by airline. Is their any SOAP or Rest api available to get this information? It would be better if anyway I can get the expiry in BFM results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the expiration of the fare indicated by the airline, this is something that BFM will not return. If you need the ticketing time limit from the PNR you can read PNRs with getReservationRQ.

Comment: in which specific node do i get time limit in getReservationRS ?

Comment: In the priceQuote if you stored one, ticketingTimeLimit I guess.